# What is the relation between Payment Request API and PWA?

Tags: e-commerce, progressive-web-apps, payment, payment-request-api

Is [Payment requests API](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/payments/) built to work as part of [PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) only, or can be used in regular web sites as well?

Comment: The same as your credit card & your Grocery store. Your store decides if it was to talk to your credit card company and accept payment from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A website becomes a PWA when it uses the PWA APIs. There's no strict technical definition of what a PWA is. It's fair to assume your website needs three things to qualify for being a PWA: you need to be running under HTTPS, you need a Web App Manifest and you need a Service Worker. The Payment requests API requires HTTPS, but that's the only matching requirement here.

So basically: no, you don't need to have a PWA to use the Payment requests API, but your website will become more PWA-like when you use it.

Comment: Thanks! would you like to answer another question in this subject as well? here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55089440/where-is-the-data-in-payment-request-api-stored